# Analytics API no longer linked to my Google account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I contacted Google Analytics support by email and they pointed me to this forum. Hope you guys can help me out.

Before I signed up for Google Apps for Work, I used to have a Google account (ex: myemail@mycompany.com).

After signing up for Google Apps for Work (with the same email) I had to choose between the old account and the new one. I chose the new one that I use right now with Google Apps for Work.

OK, and how is that related to the Google Analytics API, you may ask?

Well, on my old account I had the Google Analytics API enabled and this connection was lost when I chose to keep the new account.

My connection to Google Analytics API still works as it should, but the API is no longer linked to my account.

My question is, can you guys link the Google Analytics API to my account back?

Thanks so much for your help.

Philip

PS. I can provide my Google email account and the Google Analytics API client id on request if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for your question.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  The google Analytics API is linked to a Google Analytics account.   Accessing the Google Analytics API is done first by Creating a project on Google Developers console.  Its the project on the console that enables users to access the Google Analytics API.  So depending upon what you are using to access google analytics you may just need to re authenticate.

Comment: OK, I will try to explain better this time. :)

When I sign in to Google Developers console and go to the Enabled APIs tab, I see "No enabled APIs". I used to see the Analytics API here and now it's gone. That's because the project on the console is also gone. I believe this happened when I switched to the new account. How can I get it back, linked to my new account?

Comment: If this is not the right forum for my question, can you please point me in the right direction?